# How do I access a nested key?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

So I created a list of lists that look like this:

```
list_of_lists = [['signature', 'nn'], ['or', 'cc'], ['veto', 'nn'], ['veto', 'nn']]
```

Then I have to count the number of times identical sublists occur so I did this:

```
count = Counter(map(tuple,list_of_lists))
```

And this worked accurately, however, it saved the count as:

```
{('signature', 'nn'): 1, ('or', 'cc'): 1, ('veto', 'nn'): 2}
```

So I have a nested key, so whenever I attempt to do this:

```
for k,v in count.items():
        print(v)
        print(k)  # k prints out (veto, nn)
```

The key prints out the word and Part of Speech (POS), however, I would just like to use these items individually. So my question is how do I access each word and POS individually?

Comment: ``k[0]`` and ``k[1]``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just unpack them this way:

```
for (word, pos), v in count.items():
```